# Built-in Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

By using built in adapter on my code my app starts crashing.

````
    ListView listView;
    public String[] arr={"item1","item2","item3"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,arr);
        listView.setAdapter(ad);
    }
}```
````

Comment: What is the crash message? When does it crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array adapter requires the layout to be `TextView` only. But with layout  `activity_list_item` it's `LinearLayout` with an image & text as a child,so it will crash.

Right layout for your example would be `simple_list_item_1`

So It should look like this:

```
ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
listView.setAdapter(ad);
```